# window.print function in IE

Tags: javascript, printing, window

I have a problem regarding the window.print in javascript. I have installed cutePdfWriter so that 
the resulting "printed" page will be saved in pdf 
format first, im using this just for checking.

When I run my application in FF ang then print it using
window.print, image1 is outputted in pdf, but if I run
it in IE and print, image2 is outputted.

The image in IE is bigger and does not fit itself in the
layout.

Do you have any idea about this difference and how to
solve it that the output will be the same of that
in Firefox?

[image: output of print with Firefox]
[image: output of print with IE8]

I have placed

```
<style type='text/css'>
       * {margin:0; padding:0;} 
  </style>
```

in the head of the html and have no other margins. but still does not work. T.T
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it's a css issue that making the output of your content different in IE. Try a different css for your table only for ie using media type. Take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433064(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @SheikhHeera  yeah i thhink its css problem, giving me a hard time..:(

Comment: You'll need to post your CSS. But as a general rule of thumb: Don't give your table a fixed with in pixels.

Comment: @RoToRa that did it I was assigning fixed width size in pixels! thanks a lot! how can I flag this as correct answer? thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment: Don't give your table a fixed width in pixels.